Telethon не отображает сообщения в iter_messages
При написании парсера на основе telethon, возникла проблема.
В моём чате присутствуют сообщения от обычных пользователей, которых и нужно спарсить, но они никак не выдаются.
Мой код:
chat = await self.client.get_entity(chat)
async for msg in self.client.iter_messages(chat, reverse=True, min_id=5):
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    sender = await msg.get_sender()
    if (sender) and (sender.__class__.__name__ == "User") and (not sender.bot) and (sender.id not in list(self.result.keys())):
        if sender.username:
            self.result[sender.id] = {
                            'username': sender.username ,
                            'phone': sender.phone,
                            'status': status,
                            'premium': "Премиум" if sender.premium else "Без премиума",
                        }

Также есть еще один чат, в нем такая же ситуация

это реклама двух чатов или вопрос? если второе, то зачем нужны ссылки нв какие-то чаты?

это не реклама. Написал пример этих двух чатов, чтобы вы могли удостовериться в неработоспособности моего кода(таких как эти 2 чата, которые не собираются не так уж и много)

Отредактируйте вопрос, расставьте отступы в коде нормально, это же python, пробелы в начале строки - это часть кода.
